# Fortran - Write Statement effects subsequent calculations

Tags: fortran

I'm in the processes of debugging a legacy fortran project I've inherited (about 25,000 lines)... currently looking at a bug that seems to be related to memory allocation(?)

As part of tracking it down I have inserted a WRITE statement (as below) and have noticed that the presence of that WRITE statement affects the way the subsequent loop executes... if the write statement is there, the loop makes it to the inner most line because the test on xtd2 (j, jj3) passes.  If I then comment out the WRITE line, the comparison fails.  So the presence of the WRITE statement seems to affect the value of xtd2 (j, jj3)...

Wondering if anyone has any thoughts on how this unusual behaviour might come about?

```
               WRITE (2, '(a, 9e10.3)') 'JC1 ', xk, xtd2 (j, jj), x8 , xtd2 (j, jj2) , cl , xtd2 (j, jj5) , xkcheck , xtd2 (j, jj3) , xtd2 (j, jj4)

               IF (ABS (1.0 - (xk / xtd2 (j, jj))) < tolkn) THEN 
                   IF (ABS (x8 - xtd2 (j, jj2)) < tolerance .AND. ABS (cl - xtd2 (j, jj5)) < tolerance) THEN
                       IF (ABS (xkcheck - xtd2 (j, jj3)) < tolerance) THEN
                           IF (iconcrete .EQ. INT (xtd2 (j, jj4))) jmx = j ! jmx is assigned the index of a matching material (within tolerance)
                       END IF
                   END IF
               END IF
```

Comment: SIgh.  You need to provide some actual information.  What compiler?  What operatiing system?  What options have you used when compiling the code?  You seem to be hitting 1 of 2 classic bugs: (1) indexing an array outside of its declared range.  (2) an argument mismatch in calling a subprogram which has an implicit interface.

Comment: Thanks for the response... Excuse my greenness... my first post!... running on a Windows 10 machine, compiler is Lahey Fortran 95.  Compiling as a windows exe which is being run via a VBA macro.. using these options currently: -c -win -mod -ninfo... I'll start looking into those suggestions but let me know if this extra info helps zero in on anything....

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lahey's option, but it likely has an option to check for array bounds indexing.  I suspect that you're stepping off the end of an array.

Comment: If OP can provide evidence that this is not a duplicate of the indicated question I'll happily reopen.